# How to overwrite beginning of a device with random bits or zeros?

Tags: hard-disk, dd

Just looking to overwrite a small portion of a device with zeros or random bits. More precisely I would like to overwrite the first 1% of all the sectors or few MiB. Is there an easy way to do that ?

Comment: Calculating the odds that the random data forms a valid-enough GPT or MBR might be interesting (I use `/dev/zero` on the first bits of a device to eliminate the chance something bootable is written).

Comment: MBR has a two-byte signature for a valid partition table, so 1/65000 or less than 2*10^-5. Should be rare enough, unless you have many of thousands of drives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although `/dev/urandom` is extremely slow and as such not suitable for overwriting large amounts of data (entire disk), it might do for small regions.

Example overwriting 8MiB:

```
dd bs=1M count=8 iflag=fullblock if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/destroyme
```

Alternatively you can use `shred`:

```
shred -v -n 1 -s 8M /dev/destroyme
```

You can also use `losetup` to create devices of specific size and offsets, and overwrite them with utilities that don't have their own size / offset options.

```
losetup --find --show --offset 0 --sizelimit $((8*1024*1024)) /dev/destroyme
# will print /dev/loopX
cat /dev/urandom > /dev/loopX
losetup -d /dev/loopX
```

Comment: If `/dev/urandom` is _extremely_ slow, then how do you qualify the speed of `/dev/random`? :-)

Comment: For `/dev/random` it's about zero, because it just stops at some point. :) I seem to recall feeling that `shred` would have been slowish too, up to the point that I assumed it read straight from `/dev/urandom`. A quick `strace` shows it only reads 2048 bytes from there (that's already a lot), but I can't test the speed just now.

Comment: `shred` is cpu bound, but already gigabytes per second on a not too dated desktop PC, fast enough for storage - if you're happy with pseudorandom data. `/dev/urandom` was made slower (securer?) some kernel versions ago, tops out around `10M/s` not fast enough for USB2 disks. If you need better random than `shred` you can go through `cryptsetup`, still beats `/dev/urandom` by a long shot.

Answer (score 3):

Same as with any file to overwrite the first 10 MiB with zeros:

```
head -c10M < /dev/zero 1<> /dev/sdax
```

For block device files, the `1<>` to open without truncation is not even needed as there's no such thing as truncating a block device, so you can simply do:

```
head -c10M < /dev/zero > /dev/sdax
```

Not all head implementations support `-c`, and when they do, not all support that `M` suffix (and when they do `M` may mean megabyte (1000000 bytes) like `ksh93`'s `head` builtin or mebibyte (1048576 bytes) like GNU `head`). In that case, you can do:

```
head -c "$((10 * 1024 * 1024)"
```

to make it explicit.

If we compare with `dd bs=1M count=10 < /dev/zero > /dev/sdax`:

- conceptually

  - `head` is the command to read a specified number of bytes or lines from a file and write it to stdout
  - while `dd` is a low level command to read and write data in the exact way you want it to.

  I'd use `head` here on the ground that it's the command designed for the task. I'd use `dd` if I wanted to optimise for a specific use case, or use one of the specific features of `dd` (see also the note on portability).
- The read+write loop:

  - `head -c10M` will try and read the requested data no matter what and only fail with a non-zero exit status if an error is encountered.
  - `dd bs=1M count=10`, will do exactly 10 reads (as long as there's no error) and for each read that returns some data, do a corresponding write with the amount of data that was read. That only works as long as each read returns exactly the 1M requested. In practice, that's true for `/dev/zero`, but on Linux (4.6 at least), for `/dev/urandom`, I can't get more than 32MiB minus 1 byte in a single read (so still OK for 1MiB, though YMMV if you're using a different version of Linux), and for `/dev/random`, only a few bytes (what's currently in the entropy pool). The GNU implementation of `dd` has a `iflag=fullblock` to keep reading until the request buffer is full to behave like `head`, but if you don't have GNU `dd`, the only option is to do 1 byte reads at a time that would have dramatic impacts on the performance.
- performance:
  For anything other than small amounts (less than a few hundred megabytes) where the data is written to buffers that will be flushed to disk later, or writing to `/dev/null`, the process will be I/O bound. If reading to `/dev/urandom` or `/dev/random` the bottle neck will be either the random number generation or the disk I/O. In those cases, you won't find much difference between dd and head. In any case `head` is likely to have a higher CPU overhead (unnoticed when the performance is I/O bound).

  - `head` is a basic tool. Implementations will try to do the job as efficiently as possible while still being reliable for all types of input and output and not use too much resource. It will do the same read+write loop as `dd`, the main difference in terms of performance is the size of reads and writes which will determine the number of system calls being made.

    Those sizes will depend on the implementation and version of `head` and possibly the system. With the latest version of GNU `head` on my system, the reads are of size BUFSIZE (8KiB on GNU systems), and the writes of size 4KiB, though that can be changed with `stdbuf -o 1M` for instance.

    `ksh93`'s `head` builtin seems to do 64KiB reads and writes and doesn't use the libc's stdio, at least on my system.

    GNU `head` using stdio also means extra overhead incurred by stdio (the implementation of which is system dependant).

    Current versions of GNU `cat` use `fadvise` to tell the system that it will read the data sequentially so it can optimise caching accordingly. It's not impossible some implementations of `head` do that as well, or will do in the future. `dd` being low-level, I would expect it would only do it if you told it to (I'm not aware of any `dd` implementation that has such support).
  - `dd` is very low level, it will call the `read()` and `write()` system calls directly. You can't get much more efficient than that other than by using specialised APIs like Linux' `sendfile()`.

    It gives you much more control on the size of the `read()` and `write()`, so lets you optimise yourself based on the type of the input/output and the available resources. For instance, if you have a lot of memory available, you might as well read the whole data in one go (though in my tests while copying from /dev/zero to /dev/null, I can't see any significant improvement past a block size of 32KiB and performance even start to degrade after a blocksize of 1MiB).
- portability

  None of `-c`, `bs=10M`, `conv=fullblock` are portable. The only POSIX command to read a certain amount of data from a file is `dd`, but to use it reliably (except on `/dev/zero`), as discussed above, you need `bs=1` which means dreadful performance.
- consequence of write errors.

  Both `head` and `dd` will exit at once when trying to write past the end of the  block device. If the disk has failing sectors, that will generally not be detected because the actual writing to disk is asynchronous. With the GNU implementation of `dd`, you can force the write to be direct with `oflag=direct` which means `dd` will stop on the first error. You may want to use the default block size of 512 then if you want to write as much as possible before the first failing sector.
- consequence of read errors

  You shouldn't get any read error on /dev/zero, /dev/urandom or /dev/random. But more generally, both `head` and `dd` will exit with an error upon the first read error. With `dd`, you can carry on upon errors with `conv=noerror`. In that case, you'll probably want to add the `sync` option (`conv=noerror,sync`) so that the failed blocks are padded with zeros. `head` will not give you any option to do that as it's not been designed for that.

Alternatives.

- `pv -Ss 10M < /dev/zero > /dev/sdax` will copy those 10M and give you a progress bar. By default the read/write size are 128KiB in my test. You can change it with the `-B` option, but in my tests, 128KiB gives the best results already. `pv` has a `-E` option equivalent to `dd`'s `conv=noerror,sync`.

  On Linux, it's also good for I/O on pipes as it uses the `splice()` system call to optimise performances.
- If you want to play with the `sendfile()` system call, you can use `xfs_io`.

  ```
  xfs_io -c 'sendfile -i src 0 10M' dst
  ```

  sends 10M from src to dst. However, it only does **one** `sendfile()` and the system call can't be used on `/dev/zero`, `/dev/random` nor `/dev/urandom`. It can be used on sparse files though.

  ```
   truncate -s 1T empty-file
   xfs_io -c 'sendfile -i empty-file 0 10M' /dev/sdax
  ```

  would work but for large amounts (several Gibibytes), because that's one `sendfile()` system call, that much memory must be allocated which means it's going to be less efficient than `dd bs=1M`. Ideally, we'd want to do multiple `sendfile()`s of only a few mebibytes at a time, but I'm not aware of any command that does that.
- For `/dev/zero` input, you don't really need to *read* the data for each block you write. After all, it's only zeros. It's easy enough to create a buffer with only zeros without having to read `/dev/zero`, and we can reuse it between every write. For example:

  ```
  PERLIO=:unix perl -e '$x = pack("x" . 1024*1024); print $x for 1..10000' > /dev/sdax
  ```

to write 10000 MiB would be a lot more efficient (despite the `perl` overhead) than any solution that repeatedly reads `/dev/zero`.

Comment: `head` is very inefficient for this, you should use `dd` as the other answers suggest

Comment: @MAP, see edit. Most `head` implementation will generally have more CPU overhead than `dd`, but the performance is likely to be I/O bound (or limited by the rate random numbers can be generated for `/dev/[u]random`), so you probably won't notice a performance difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dd` to do that using the `/dev/urandom` device which will provide you with random data. An example :

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sdX bs=1M count=100
```

this will write 100mbyte of random data :

- `if` is the input file
- `of` is the output file
- `bs=1M` is the block size 1Mbyte
- `count` is how many times should be this blocks written

You can as well use as input file `/dev/zero`, `/dev/null` or anything else which provides you data. This command will start writing the data at the beginning of the output file/device.

Comment: You probably want `/dev/urandom` to avoid blocking.  Or `/dev/zero` if you just want all zeros.

Comment: Without `iflag=fullblock` it will write only a few kilobytes of data due to incomplete reads.

Comment: i don't agree with you @frostschutz because i use this command every single day almost to erase certain corporate drive's filesystem/partition information. The command what i gave as example, will write 100mbytes of random data to the beginning of /dev/sdX (Ubuntu).

Comment: I commented before you edited it... http://paste.ubuntu.com/21032081/ — `/dev/null` as input will copy 0 bytes. :)

Comment: /dev/null - yes, it will write 0 bytes. but /dev/zero works like a charm. I only changed /dev/random to /dev/urandom, as /dev/random requires the flag you mentioned, but /dev/urandom doesn't